# Find all <img> tags, remove height and width and then put the removed values in the style of the <img> tag

Tags: php, html, css, styles, preg-replace

So I am trying to find a way to get `<img>` tags from a string remove the width and height of the image and put that info in the style part of the image. Something like this:

I have a string:

```
<p><img src="image1.jpg" border="0" alt="" hspace="0" vspace="0" width="400px" height="200px" style="display: block; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;" /></p>
<p style="text-align: justify;">Some text</p>
<p><img src="iamge2.jpg" border="0" alt="" hspace="0" vspace="0" width="600px" height="300px" style="display: block; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;" /></p>
```

and I would like to get something like this:

```
 <p><img src="image1.jpg" border="0" alt="" hspace="0" vspace="0" style="width:100%; max-width:400px; display: block; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;" /></p>
 <p style="text-align: justify;">Some text</p>
 <p><img src="iamge2.jpg" border="0" alt="" hspace="0" vspace="0" style="width:100%; max-width:400px; display: block; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;" /></p>
```

I tried with `preg_replace` but it seems I don't understand it well.

Any help is much appreciated. Darko

Comment: Don't use regexes on HTML. This is a trivial operation with [DOM](http://php.net/dom)...

Answer (score 1):

If the HTML code is valid as XHTML, you can use [SimpleXML](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.simplexml.php) to find and replace elements and attributes.